# make bjam run a script before compiling

Tags: bjam

Is it possible to have bjam run a script prior to building? If so, how? I would like apply a patch to the code before compiling, but do not want to change the normal workflow for developers. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's one way I've found that is quick

```
Echo [ SHELL "./myscript" ] ;
```

or you could use [generators](http://www.boost.org/boost-build2/doc/html/bbv2/extending/tools.html)